# Configure Wildfly in Docker so that Arquillian can deploy to it

Tags: docker, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I would like to create Arquillian tests that run on a Wildfly server in a Docker container.

### Step 1: let's keep it simple, and leave Docker out of the picture

I have written Arquillian tests that deploy on a **remote** Wildfly.

When I set up an unchanged, empty, standalone Wildfly server, Arquillian deploys the tests + dependent ears and then they run without any issue. Awesome!

### Step 2 (here comes the problem): let's replace the local Wildfly with a containerized Wildfly

The next step is to put **Wildfly in a Docker container**, and let my Arquillian tests run on that containerised Wildfly. As far as I can tell, I have to make sure that

- the right ports are open, more specifically 8080
- there is an administrator user configured, which Arquillian can use to do deployments

I think I have done that correctly. When I run my Docker image,

- I get an empty Wildfly,
- which I can reach on localhost:8080 (Welcome to Wildlfly screen)
- and localhost:9990 (administrator console, I can log in as administrator)

*When I run the tests, I get*

```
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
```

Weird, since I can get in the browser to the management console just fine.

**Does anyone see my oversight? Did I forget anything?**

### Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  arquillian-cube-wildfly-test:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9990:9990"
      - "8787:8787"
```

#### Dockerfile

```
# Base image: Wildfly 10 with 8080 port exposed
FROM jboss/wildfly:10.1.0.Final

# Open management port
EXPOSE 9990
EXPOSE 8787

# Add management user with password
RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin --silent

# Set the default command to run on boot
# This will boot WildFly in the standalone mode and bind to all interface
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

#### The test project

Check out https://github.com/stainii/arquillian-cube-and-multiple-deployments-experiment.
It's a multi-module Maven project, containing

- first-webapp (dummy project, which will be tested by the tests)
- second-webapp (dummy project, which will be tested by the tests)
- integration-tests (the project that contains the tests)

To run this:

1. start up the Docker container by going to src/test/resources/wildfly, and execute `docker-compose up`.
2. Build the project and start the tests with `mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies install`. The 2 webapps will be built, their ears will be copied to the target of the test project, and the Arquillian tests will deploy these ears and run tests.

Comment: Here is another example that might help you out - https://github.com/sfcoy/jaxrs-people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your projects.

1.Wrong configuration in arquillian.xml. Check https://git.io/vNaYu for correct configuration of arquillian.xml

2.You are using old version of arquillian-container in your profile `arq-widlfly-remote`. It should be

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
  <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If you are getting timeout error with this setup, its the default connectionTimeout is set too low. Increasing it in my arquillian.xml config fixed my problem.